# How can I install portia2.08 on ubuntu14.04,

Tags: python

I installed portia2 on Ubuntu14.04 according to the installation instructions on GitHub, and everything went smoothly. But when I run portia using `slyd/bin/slyd -p 9002 -r portiaui/dist & portia_server/manage.py runserver`, the following error occurred:

```
Successfully installed slybot
python@ubuntu:~/Desktop/portia2/portia$ 
PYTHONPATH='/vagrant/portia_server:/vagrant/slyd:/vagrant/slybot'
python@ubuntu:~/Desktop/portia2/portia$ slyd/bin/slyd -p 9002 -r 
portiaui/dist &[1] 10526
python@ubuntu:~/Desktop/portia2/portia$ portia_server/manage.py 
runserver2017-09-19 00:42:27-0700 [-] Log opened.
2017-09-19 00:42:27.135148 [-] Splash version: 2.3.3
2017-09-19 00:42:27.159967 [-] WARNING: Lua scripting is not available 
because 'lupa' Python package is not installed
2017-09-19 00:42:27.160091 [-] Qt 5.5.1, PyQt 5.5.1, WebKit 538.1, sip 4.17, 
Twisted 16.1.1
2017-09-19 00:42:27.160236 [-] Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4]
2017-09-19 00:42:27.160299 [-] Open files limit: 1024
2017-09-19 00:42:27.160345 [-] Open files limit increased from 1024 to 4096
2017-09-19 00:42:27.297087 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':831598118', '-
screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":831598118".
2017-09-19 07:42:35.659210 [-] Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-09-19 07:42:35.659549 [-]   File "slyd/bin/slyd", line 34, in <module>
2017-09-19 07:42:35.659750 [-]     
splash.server.main(server_factory=make_server, argv=[])
2017-09-19 07:42:35.659915 [-]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/splash/server.py", line 372, in main
2017-09-19 07:42:35.660109 [-]     server_factory=server_factory,
2017-09-19 07:42:35.660267 [-]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/splash/server.py", line 291, in default_splash_server
2017-09-19 07:42:35.660448 [-]     
argument_cache_max_entries=argument_cache_max_entries,
2017-09-19 07:42:35.660582 [-]   File "slyd/bin/slyd", line 31, in 
make_server
2017-09-19 07:42:35.660749 [-]     'docroot': opts.root}))
2017-09-19 07:42:35.660895 [-]   File 
"/home/python/Desktop/portia2/portia/slyd/slyd/tap.py", line 88, in 
makeService
2017-09-19 07:42:35.661046 [-]     root = create_root(config, 
settings_module)
2017-09-19 07:42:35.661175 [-]   File 
"/home/python/Desktop/portia2/portia/slyd/slyd/tap.py", line 61, in 
create_root
2017-09-19 07:42:35.661350 [-]     for file_name in 
listdir(config['docroot']):
2017-09-19 07:42:35.661495 [-] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'portiaui/dist'
```

What do I need to do to fix this?